# Recipient User Language email alert in workflow

Tags: visualforce, email-template

How to get the recipient's language in a visualforce email?

I'm trying to use this property:

> language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}"

But when the email is sent, the recipient object is the context user, and not the user who will receive the email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you store the recipient's language? Is the recipient a contact, a user or a lead?. You need to pass that value to the language tag.http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

Comment: The recipient is an User. And the field with the language is "LanguageLocaleKey".

Comment: Have you verified that the language is enabled in the translation workbench and that you have a translation for those values?

Comment: We are having a similar issue when using language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}" in VF email template , have you been able to resolve this ? I have found this known Salesforce issue which may be related :
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SdBfAAK Best Regards,
Shamina

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<messagingmessaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.subject}" recipientType="Contact"
relatedToType="Account" language="{!recipient.language__c}">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
{!$Label.greeting}
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: what is the value in `{!$Label.greeting}` ? i have in the same situation not sure how to do it, have a look https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162817/multi-lingual-visualforce-email-templates

Comment: You have to create a custom label.  Greeting is one such custom label.  In the custom label, you will mention the translated version also for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar sort of problem in which even though relatedToType="Opportunity" and language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}" was mentioned in the VF template still the translation was not reflecting.

My business case was to translate the email template as per the opportunity's owner language.

I replaced language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}" with language="{!relatedTo.owner.languageLocaleKey}" and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the above solution worked for you, but if it didn't try this:
language="{!relatedTo.LanguageLocaleKey}"

Answer (score 0):

The `recipient` merge fields are available in Visualforce email templates, but there is [a note on the Email Alert Actions article that states](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_wfalerts_recipienttypes.htm&type=5):

> The Recipient merge field isn’t supported in either Classic or Lightning email templates used for workflows.

I've taken this to mean that the `recipient` value is unavailable if the email is sent via an Email Alert and my testing has reflected this.
However it is available using other methods (including the "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" button) which makes this a particularly tricky issue to deal with. My alternative has been to reference the language via `relatedTo` when I know the email template is used in conjunction with an Email Alert.