# Community Welcome Email Translation in 8 other languages

Tags: email, email-template, community-builder, customlabel

I am using classic Email Template with html version to send the welcome email. For the translation I am using custom label {!$label.label_name}.

If I select the language french in community the email still coming in English(default language).

Any Suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @identigral That's vf email template and the answer does not seem to apply here for standard HTML email.

Comment: If you use VF rather than HTML templates, here's an option: [Multi-lingual Visualforce email templates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162817/multi-lingual-visualforce-email-templates)

Comment: @user90674 Have you also created translations for these labels using the translation workbench?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I have created the translation. It is working if I change the user language and try from "send test and verify merge fields". But not working If I try from my community

Comment: seems not possible as per this idea https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kuG1AAI

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Is there any other solution to translate. Will this VF email template will work?

Comment: Try with a vf template to see if it works! Try using the below https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000UYjkQAG

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Visualforce email template and set the `LanguageLocaleKey` appropriately on the recipient you can craft an email like so:

```html
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.Welcome_Email_Subject}" recipientType="User" language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>
                    <!-- We can craft a custom label like this: "Hello {0} {1}" and have our translations follow accordingly. -->
                    <apex:outputText value="{!$Label.Salutation}">
                        <apex:param value="{!recipient.FirstName}" />
                        <apex:param value="{!recipient.LastName}" />
                    </apex:outputText>    
                </p>
                <p>{!$Label.Welcome_Instructions}</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}">{!$Label.Welcome_Link_Text}</a>
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

The key is liberal use of custom labels to allow the whole email body to be translated. Leverage the merge fields that are available when using `apex:outputText` (replacing `{0}` and `{1}` with values) if you need to re-order things like subject-verb agreement in a translation.